# How does Type Coercion in Javascript in the case of object to boolean?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

To the best of my knowledge, `(x == false)` should do the same thing as `!x`, as both of them try to interpret `x` as a boolean, and then negates it.

However, when I tried to test this out, I started getting some extremely strange behavior.

For example:

`false == []` and `false == ![]` both return true.

Additionally

`false == undefined` and `true == undefined` both return false, as does

`false == Infinity` and `true == Infinity` and

`false == NaN` and `true == NaN`.

What exactly is going on here?

http://jsfiddle.net/AA6np/1/

Comment: Do you get the same results with `===`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: you know he doesn't, because those are different types on both sides...

Comment: well `false === []` is obviously false, as is `true === []`, considering `[]`,`undefined`,`Infinity`, and `NaN` are not booleans.

Comment: `false == []` can be explained as `[].toString() == ""`, and `false == ""`.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds as if you believe that, if `false == undefined` returns false, then `true == undefined` should return true, but really why should these kinds of comparisons return anything meaningful at all?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it doesn't, this is an academic exercise. obviously anybody writing if(![] == false) should be fired.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Yes, the question was rhetorical.

Comment: What is the **opposite of `undefined`** anyway? As in `!undefined`?

Comment: Yes I agree that the array one is the most baffling. A great find! Isn't there an old community wiki that has all kinds of Javascript strangeness? This should definitely be posted on the list there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all here: http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3

For the case of `false == []`:

- `false` is converted to a number (0), because that is always done with booleans.
- [] is converted to a primitive by calling `[].valueOf().toString()`, and that is an empty string.
- `0 == ""` is then evaluated by converting the empty string to a number, and because the result of that is also 0, `false == []` is true.

For the case of `false == ![]`:

- The [logical not operator `!`](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.9) is performed by returning the opposite of `ToBoolean(GetValue(expr))`
- [`ToBoolean()`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2) is always true for any object, so `![]` evaluates to `false` (because `!true = false`), and therefore is `false == ![]` also true.

---

`(false == undefined) === false` and `(true == undefined) === false` is even simpler:

- `false` and `true` are again converted to numbers (0 and 1, respectively).
- Because undefined cannot be compared to a number, the chain bubbles through to the default result and that is `false`.

The other two cases are evaluated the same way: First Boolean to Number, and then compare this to the other number. Since neither 0 nor 1 equals Infinity or is Not A Number, those expressions also evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The abstract equality algorithm is described in [section 9.3 of the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3).

For `x == y` where x = `false` and y = `[]`:

1. Nope. Types are not equal.
2. Nope, x is not null.
3. Nope. x is not undefined.
4. Nope, x is not a number
5. Nope, x is not a string.
6. Yes, x is a boolean, so we compare ToNumber(x) and y.

Repeat the algorithm, x=`0` and y=`[]`.
We end at step 8:Type(x) == number. and Type(y) == object.
So, let the result be x == [ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.com/#x9.1)(y).
ToPrimitive([]) == ""

Now, repeat the algorithm again with x=`0` and y=`""`. We end at 4: "return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y)."
ToNumber("") == 0

The last repetition of the algorithm ends at step 1 (types are equal). By 1.c.iii, 0 == 0, and true is returned.

The other results can be obtained in a similar manner, by using the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
false == []
```

Using `==` Javascript is allowed to apply conversions. The object will convert into a primitive to match type with the boolean, leaving an empty string. The false will convert into a number 0. The compares the empty string and the number 0. The string is converted to a number which will be 0, so the expression is "true"

```
![]
```

Javascript converts the object to the boolean true, therefore denying true ends being false.

```
false == undefined true == undefined
false == Infinity and true == Infinity
false == NaN and true == NaN
```

Again a bit of the same! false is converted to 0, true to 1. And then, undefined is converted to a number which is... NaN! So false in any case

I would recommend to use `=== !==` as much as you can to get "expected" results unless you know very well what you are doing. Using something like `Boolean(undefined) == fals`e would also be nice.

Check ECMAScript specifications for all the details when converting stuff.