# Why is tab equal to false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I thought I knew about the quirks with `==` and all the strange type casts in JavaScript, but today I stumbled upon one thing that doesn't make *any* sense to me:

```
'\t' == false
// => true
```

Why is that?

Apparently, `'\t'` is not a falsy value, and if combined with `||` it works as excpected:

```
'\t' || 42
// => '\t'
```

On the other hand, a `toString` is also not called on `false`, see:

```
'\t' == 'false'
// => false
```

This led me to thinking that the tab maybe gets converted to a boolean, but:

```
Boolean('\t') == false
// => false
```

So, the question is: Why is that?

Comment: 1. Javascript is weird with true and false
2. mainly because a tab is a whitespace and in terms of use cases you usually dont condider an empty string as a word with value
imagine having an input mask then you can check wether it has values by doing `if(inputstirng){...}`

Comment: `'\n' == false` true as well

Comment: "\t" is an "emtpy" string

Comment: @jonathanHeindl minor nitpick : Javascript is weird. Not just for booleans.

Comment: They should add `'\t'` to https://eqeq.js.org/ (What's your score there? ;-) )

Comment: Closely related: [How does Type Coercion in Javascript in the case of object to boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11264974/1048572). Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/664886/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23693089/1048572)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

See [Abstract Equality Comparison:](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

> The comparison `x == y`, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:

So, in your situation, `x` is a string, and `y` is a boolean. The first condition that is fulfilled here is:

> 9. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.

Turning the check into

```
'\t' == 0
```

Which then fulfills:

> 7. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

And `ToNumber('\t') === 0`:

```js
console.log(Number('\t'));
```

Turning the check into

```
0 == 0
```

which is the same as

```
0 === 0
```

or `true`.

Note that while a string composed of all whitespace is `== false`, calling Boolean on such a string will return `true`, because the string has a non-zero length:

```js
console.log(
  Boolean(' '),
  Boolean('\t')
);
```

Of course, it would be best to always avoid `==` - use `===` instead, and you won't have to worry about these silly coercion rules.